# How to turn sequence diagrams into python code?

Tags: python, uml, code-generation, sequence-diagram

I am currently trying to convert a sequence diagram into python code as part of a forward engineering process. But I'm struggling with the definition of the functions. Is there any way I can generate or transform python code from an UML sequence diagram ? I used this diagram as a reference

[image: I used this diagram as a reference]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Besides the fact that your question is off-topic here I heavily doubt this will be possible and/or useful. A SD shows only an aspect of a class's operations. And you can't easily deduct behavior. So you just get a few operation headers. That's done manually the same speed and you can start thinking about what you have to do in the end.

Comment: Perhaps this tool could help [Generating Python from UML](https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/docs/code-engineering/instant-generator/how-to-generate-python-from-uml/)